# Proc Import always changes last column name to VARx

Tags: sas

I am trying to import a csv using proc import.

```
proc import datafile='/SourceFiles/UserTable.csv'
     out=UserTable dbms=csv replace; 
     getnames=yes;
run;
```

The column names are captured correctly except for the last.  The last column always changes to VARx.  For testing purposes, I even change my dataset to have one column and one value so that it's like

**USER** 

Johnson

But USER changes to Var1 as well.  I'm pretty sure I'm not violating any naming conventions.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Post the code being generated in the log. Also look at datarow or firstobs option.

Comment: I do not have any trouble reading a file with USER as the column header.  How did you detect the error? Note that if you attempt to reference a variable named USER in a PROC SQL Select statement then you will get strange results.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it worked for me using sas 9.3

```
proc import datafile="C:\Users\OldSalt\Desktop\test.csv" 
      out=mydata   
      dbms=csv
      replace;          
      getnames=yes;
run;
```

So, this looks the same as your script.  My is running just fine on a PC.  It looks like you are running on a UNIX box.  Check your input file.  It might be corrupted.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the difference between PC and UNIX box.  I am using a PC.  I don't think my input file is corrupt because I made a new file and copied those values in and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I realized options VALIDVARNAME=v7 is what's messing me up.